# MouseWheel up and down bindings not working in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

I am working with the following code -

```
self.table.Table.bind("<MouseWheel-Down>", lambda x: self.table.shiftTable('right'))
self.table.Table.bind('<MouseWheel-Up>', lambda x: self.table.shiftTable('left'))          #mousewheel up and down not working for unknown reasons
self.table.Table.bind('<KeyPress-Left>', lambda x: self.table.shiftTable('left'))
self.table.Table.bind('<KeyPress-Right>', lambda x: self.table.shiftTable('right'))
self.table.Table.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: self.table.Table.focus())
self.table.Table.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: self.mainUI_object.fg_root.focus())
```

The problem here is that the mousewheel bindings are not working though not giving errors. On the other hand the following code piece works (note the absence of up and down specifiers) -

```
self.table.Table.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda x: self.table.shiftTable('right'))
```

What can be the possible reasons for not working and what is the solution to get the up and down work?

Comment: Are you trying to combine mouswheel + up key? and also what machine are you on?

Comment: Yes, trying to combine mousewheel + up key. I am on a Windows desktop pc.

Comment: So practically while scrolling and pressing the `up` or `down` keys the event should trigger, right?

Comment: No, I meant the scroll up from the 'mousewheel + up'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows and Mac, `<MouseWheel-Down/Up>` is not a binding to turning the mouse wheel up or down, instead it corresponds to simultaneously using the mouse wheel and pressing the Down/Up arrow key. The MouseWheel binding cannot be made direction specific, however the direction of the scrolling is contained in `event.delta`. This means you can do something like

```
def mouse_wheel_binding(self, event):
    if event.delta > 0: 
        self.table.shiftTable('right')
    else:
        self.table.shiftTable('left')
```

and

```
self.table.Table.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.mouse_wheel_binding)
```

I don't have Windows or Mac so I don't know which sign correspond to Up/Down, so you might have to switch the left/right.

Note: In Linux, the mouse wheel bindings are direction specific: MouseWheel-Up is `'<Button-4>'` and MouseWheel-Down is  `'<Button-5>'`and the `"<MouseWheel>"` binding does not work.

Comment: Thanks, its working. You have just got a mistake of extra bracket in the last line 
 self.table.shiftTable('left')). Everything else is ok!

Comment: But, I have one more concern, the <Mousewheel-Up> and <Mousewheel-Down> never gave errors. What can be the reasons?

Comment: `'<Mousewheel-Up>'` is a valid binding: Mouse wheel + Up arrow key